# SQL Insert Into Statement to pass SAS date to MS Access DB

Tags: sql, ms-access, sas

I would like to append the data in a SAS dataset to a table in a MS Access database. In the past, I've used a SQL INSERT INTO statement to do this, but I'm having some trouble with inserting the SAS date field into the MS Access Date/Time field. Here's an idea of what I'm trying do in the SAS program:

```
libname input "c:\Folder";
libname db access 'C:\Folder\database.accdb';

Proc SQL;
Create table tblAccess as
Select distinct field1, field2, DOS
from input.dat1;

PROC SQL;
Insert into db.tblClaims (field1, field2, DOS)
select field1, field2, DOS
from work.tblAccess;
```

The problem with this is that the DOS field is showing up as "1/1/1960 5:52:XX AM" in the MS Access database, regardless of what the DOS was originally. Obviously, the issue is that the SAS date is being entered into MS Access as a datetime - the SAS date of 12/10/2017 is being stored as the numeric 21163, which is being inserted into the MS Access DB as 21,163 seconds (~5 hours, 52 minutes) from 1/1/1960. In other words, somewhere along the way, my days are being treated as seconds, throwing everything off, if that makes sense.

But while I understand the issue, I can't seem to figure out how to fix it. Alternatively, I'd appreciate suggestions for other ways to approach this task that avoids this date/time field issue. As far as I can tell, PROC EXPORT won't work because the exported SAS dataset replaces the MS Access table and can't append to it, at least from my experiments with it.

Edit: the SAS field is DATE9. and the MS Access field is Date/Time, in case that's relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to start off by saying I don't have experience with the exact problem you've encountered, but perhaps something similiar. Also, its been years since I have worked with `sas` on any serious level.

That being said, you *most likely* want to work with the format of the date field in question. Something like this *may* work:

```
Data tblAccess;
SET work.tblAccess;
Format DOS YYMMDD10.;
run;
```

OR Alternatively (in the Proc SQL):

```
Proc SQL;
Create table tblAccess as
Select DISTINCT field1, 
    field2, 
    DOS format=YYMMDD10.
from input.dat1;
```

It's been too long for me to know for sure what Format you need, but a general review of other possible formats with a search engine check may yield the answer you need (assuming this doesn't work).

Answer (score 1):

Re-stating the problem for Stack Overflow helped me see the solution. If the problem is that days are being turned into seconds, why not turn them back into days? I added the following DATA step in before the second PROC SQL statement:

```
Data tblAccess;
set work.tblAccess;
DOS = DOS*86400;
Format DOS Datetime9.;
run;
```

It appears to have resolved the issue. However, I would still appreciate better methods to perform this task.

Comment: You seem to have worded the description backwards. Your operation is converting number of days into number of seconds by multiplying by the number of seconds in a day.  Equivalently you could use a time literal for the number of seconds: `datetime=date*'24:00:00't;`  Or just the `dhms()` function.

Answer (score 1):

SAS stores date values as the number of days and datetime values as the number of seconds. You can convert from date to datetime using the `DHMS()` function. DHMS  stands for Days Hours Minutes Seconds,   You can convert the other way using the `datepart()` function.

```
insert into db.tblClaims (field1, field2, datetime_field)
  select field1, field2, dhms(date_field,0,0,0)
  from work.tblAccess
;
```